# List in Python help needed: how to Avoid calling repetitive code

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have a function shown below:

```py
def _extract_parent(matched_list, json_data, info_type):
    return [json_data[match_lst][info_type] for match_lst in matched_list]

parent_lst = list(map(lambda x: _extract_parent(x,json_data, "parent_info"), flashtext_matched_pattern))

family_lst = list(map(lambda x: _extract_parent(x, json_data, "family_info"),flashtext_matched_pattern))
```

This code works for me. But I wish to optimize it
I keep calling the map from the outside instead I want to do the mapping inside the _extract_parent function and call the function like

```py
res = _extract_parent(flashtext_matched_pattern, json_data, "parent_info")
```

My JSON looks like this:

```
{ "power series": {
        "parent_info" : "abc",
        "family_info" : "xyz",
        "base_info" : "pqr"
  }
}
```

flashtext_matched_pattern is a list of list which looks like below. It can have empty list as well as values shown in the example

```
[[],
 ['power series'],
 [],
 [],
 [],
 []]
```

So if the power series is matched it will give me the info I requested example parent_info or family_info.

Now I wish to optimize the code. I want to augment _extract_parent function to include mapping part too and call the _extract_parent function like

```py
parent_lst = _extract_parent(flashtext_matched_pattern, json_data, "parent_info")
family_lst = _extract_parent(flashtext_matched_pattern, json_data, "family_info")
```

How can I do the same? Any help in this would be highly appreciated

Or am I thinking in the wrong direction would it be a better solution? If for each matching entry, return a tuple containing metadata parent, family and base info. (If yes how to do that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your long statements where you call your code via `map` and a `lambda` are just an inconvinient way of doing another list comprehension:

```
parent_lst = [_extract_parent(x,json_data, "parent_info")
              for x in  flashtext_matched_pattern]
```

If you want to do everything in to the function, you can make that happen with a nested list comprehension:

```
def _extract_parent(list_of_match_lists, json_data, info_type):
    return [
             [json_data[match][info_type] for match in match_list]
             for match_list in list_of_match_lists
           ]
```